# MongoDB passing ObjectIds in HTTP request query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, http, express

I may not have enough understanding of how HTTP request queries work. Basically I'm trying to send an array of ObjectIDs in a http request query to my express server.

```
const query = {
  ids: [
    new ObjectID(),
    new ObjectID(),
  ],
};
console.log(query);
// { ids: [ 5ab3c6d4e70fa8c8f371d812, 5ab3c6d4e70fa8c8f371d813 ] }
```

When I pass the object to my `GET` request query and receive it on my express server backend, I get the following output:

```
function (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.query);
  // { ids: 
  //   { _bsontype: [ 'ObjectID', 'ObjectID' ],
  //     id: [ 'Z����\u000f���q�\u0012', 'Z����\u000f���q�\u0013' ] }
  // }
}
```

Any clues on how to get the actual ObjectIds from a `GET` request query?

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

console.log( JSON.stringify(req.query) );

Comment: Nopes, not a solution it just stringifies the object